# Dummy and Heckman

Tags: stata, categorical-data

I'm using Heckman Selection Model which are two consist of 2 equation. i'm using Probit as a selection equation and multiple regression as a result equation. 
how can put in dummy variables in those equation ?
Do we have to make the variables into logaritmic form ?
How can I make logaritmic variables with stata ?

Thank you..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is mostly about how to use Stata. (It's not a good idea to bundle quite different small questions together in posting to **any** forum.) It's not suitable in my view for migration to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [As the previous comment shows, I was against migrating this to SO.] @dewi rohma wati: You really need to read the documentation. Some of these questions are too low level to be appropriate for a programming forum. Find out about Stata commands `search`, `help`, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about questions of Stata usage, some very elementary. It falls between CV and SO and isn't in my view a good fit for any SE site. (It is not even in good condition for Statalist.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might do what you ask. The example looks at the effect of being a union member on log wages:

```
webuse union3
gen log_wage = ln(wage)
etregress log_wage age grade i.smsa i.black tenure, treat(union = i.south i.black tenure) twostep
```

`etregress` estimates an average treatment effect of an endogenous binary-treatment variable. In plain English, that means the "first-stage" is a probit. Estimation is by either full maximum likelihood or a two-step consistent estimator, as above.

The dummies are created on the fly by putting an `i.` in front of the covariates. This is called factor variable notation, and it also makes interactions a breeze. You can also do `tab race, gen(d_)` to create d_1, d_2, and d_3 (3 race dummies, one of which you can drop).